# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^n + a*n}{e^{3n}}$ converges for all $a > 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My thoughts: I can split the series into $\frac{1}{e^{2n}} + \frac{an}{e^{3n}}$, and I guess since $e^{3n}$ is exponentially bigger than $a*n$, it wouldn't matter what $a$ was. But with that reasoning, $a$ could be negative too.

Comment: It is enough to notice that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^k e^{-C n}$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb N$ and $C>0$ (try prove this!) this can be done by a comparison test or by ratio test

Comment: Correct: for any $a\in\Bbb R$, the series converges

Comment: Great, good to know that my reasoning is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that eventually $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}\quad e^n\ge an$ then for n sufficiently large the series is positive and we can apply, for example, limit comparison test with $\frac 1{n^2}$ to show convergence.

Comment: Or by comparison with the geometric series $\sum 2e^{-2n}$ because for all  sufficiently large $n$ we have $0<(e^n+an)e^{-3n}$  which is less than $(2e^n)e^{-3n)=2e^{-2n}$..... (The "less-than" symbol on my keyboard is currently doing wierd things.)